# How to simulate user click programmatically on this specific website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, frontend

I'm trying to trigger click using javascript on date-picker-like-element. 
This is intended for puppeter headless browser integration, but first i need my code to work in devtools console.

However it is not working... unlike normal manual click. 
I've been trying to figure this out for hours already

The particular website is here (using react)

https://www.homeaway.co.uk/p4787689

You have to click on "check in stay" for modal datepicker to appear, then my intention is to perform javascript click on one of date numbers. "1", "2", "3"... visible below

[This is how date picker looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhPAz.png)

The html structure of single date entry (which we want to click) is following:
Each date (01.08.2019, 02.08.2019 etc) is "td" row. It's class has even "clickable" in name. So it should be element that we want to click.

```
<td class="day no-gridlines selectable clickable" data-column="4" data-row="1" tabindex="-1" aria-label="August 9, 2019" aria-hidden="false">

    <div class="calendar-template calendar-template--show-availability calendar-template--show-selectability">
        <div class="day-template day-template--available-stay day-template--available-checkin-checkout">
            <div class="day-template__border">
            </div>
            <div class="day-template__content">
                <div class="day-template__day">9</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

I have tried to get each of these TD elements:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.day.no-gridlines.selectable.clickable')
```

then click one of them

```
document.querySelectorAll('.day.no-gridlines.selectable.clickable')[4].click()
```

However it is not working?

I tried to inspect event click handlers however the website is using some framework.. so it's very hard for beginner like me.

Perhaps someone more experienced can advise, why i can't execute a click on that website?

Comment: Have you checked what `...[4]`actually is? Is it a clickable element? Is it actually in the DOM? _are you sure_?

Comment: I am not sure I understand how you are trying to programmatically click on a commercial website.   Are you trying to load this site into an iframe or something and then perform actions on the iframe?  Javascript has a lot of safeguards against cross site scripting, so having a script that isn't loaded from that website itself perform operations on the site is basically impossible unless that site sets a policy that allows you to do it from your site...  If you can explain what you're trying to do better, we can see if we can help!

Comment: I'm doing automation using puppeter (headless browser). First i test the selector and code in console of regular browser, especially when something is not working (like now). How else can the datepicker can be working without onclick handler? It depends clearly on click.. i  manually click the date, it gets highlighted and i can select checkout date. Calling click() returns undefined.. not any other error so i guess element is valid to be clickable. Really getting out of ideas here. Is there any other way to capture click website could be utilizing? Something that click() does not cover?

Comment: Perhaps the datepicker is being generated on DOM ready or on window load complete. So you have to postpone your codes after datepicker (if you have access to datepicker callback function) or put your code in a timer and trigger it some seconds after document load.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the problem . I'm testing it manually in chrome after the page has been loaded with console. So onload() is not a factor, all libs have been loaded and page fully rendered

Comment: The click handler itself is on the `$('.picker__overlay')` so that's what you need to click.  And to get the right one, you may need to use a descendant selector of the one you want, like `$('.form-combined__input1 .picker__overlay').click();`  (I'm using jquery there...)  There are multiple ones of those on the screen, because the top check in/out and side check in/out for the specific property are built the same, so you may have to filter it more specifically.  But something long those lines should work

Comment: @ReverendPete are you refering to clicking on "Check in" or "check out"? There's no problem clicking on these two in order to get modal popup. I just dont know how to make click on the particular dates during date selection (after modal popup come up with datepicker). See screenshot link from initial post. Each date is seperate TD row.

Comment: Sorry, I totally misunderstood your issue.   The one thing I notice that might be of consequence is that the `td.day.selectable.clickable` elements don't actually have a click handler, they have an `onMouseDown` handler.   So maybe try triggering a `mouseDown` event, instead of a click.

Comment: @ReverendPete just a feedback that your solution has solved mine multi-day pain! One of these handlers worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Would be better if you show a page, where there are, these clickable elems (because on your link I cant find even one with the class clickable)... Anyway, try this in console:

```
javascript:function AutoClickOnThese()
{
    var targets = document.querySelectorAll(".clickable");
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(targets, function(target,index){
        //If the clicks start some ajax request, these sure will be restricted
        //if too much running in an unrealistic time
        //... if there are no ajax, just delete the timeout stuff
        setTimeout(function()
        {
            target.onclick();
            //target.click(); //if not working the onclick
        }, index*600);
    });
};
AutoClickOnThese();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! In my link you can select the "check in" and "check out dates" on the right of page. When you click one of these a modal calendar popup will appear.  And it's about that poped-up modal calendar. I'd like to simulate a click on one of the dates available there e.g "3 august 2019". The HTML structure i mentioned is part of that modal calendar - where each date is "TD" row. I tried running your code with commenting/uncommenting, but didnt work out